# How do i fix the error that says "syntax error OnClickListener, delete this token"

Tags: android

private class Button OnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener

{

int location;

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between `Button` and `OnClickListener`; the compiler is expecting `implements`, `extends`, `{` or `<` or ...  whatever comes after the class name. Deleting the space should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your class shouldn't have a space.  Try ButtonOnClickListener.  Also, be careful when giving your own classes the same name as a built-in class, such as Button.  You'll have to make sure you're only importing the desired class or use the full package name when declaring variables of this type.